# Iterating x Times a with a function and rbind

Tags: r, for-loop, rbind

I'm relatively new to R (and coding in general). I want to create a new vertex (or a 1 column dataframe). The data is related to geologic ages, which is why the numbers are so large.

The idea is to create a preliminary data set, define a function which takes the last row of that dataset which adds a value to it, insert the result back into the data set.

How would I iterate this over a set number of attempts (e.g., n=10)? is a for-loop required, and if so, how would I implement this?

```
Ages <- matrix(c(10000000,20000000,30000000,40000000),nrow=4,ncol=1)

periods <- function(Ages){
  output <- tail(Ages,n=1)+10000000
  return(output)
}

Ages <- rbind(Ages,periods(tail(Ages,n=1)))
```

Comment: Are you always extending `Ages` by the same time step? 10000000 in this case?

Answer (score 0):

It is easier if you keep the initial object a vector and then convert it to a df last if you want.  Here is one way to do it with your numbers scaled for readibility:

```
Ages <- 1:4 * 100
Ages
[1] 100 200 300 400
last <- Ages[length(Ages)]
last
[1] 400
add_val <- 1000
n_adds <- 10
new_tail <- cumsum(c(last, rep(add_val, n_adds)))
new_tail
[1]   400  1400  2400  3400  4400  5400  6400  7400  8400  9400 10400
Ages2 <- c(Ages[1:length(Ages) - 1], new_tail)
Ages2
 [1]   100   200   300   400  1400  2400  3400  4400  5400  6400  7400  8400  9400 10400
```

The code can be written more compactly, but I want to show you the process flow and also how the powerful vectorization paradigm can be used in R.